# Firebug find script hiding my element

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've been using firebug for years now but never to its full potential. i've never really done a great deal of javascript debugging with it.

Heres my problem:

I have an element on my page that is disappearing on mouseOver if the page had just one or two custom js files this would be pretty easy to debug. However the site has loads.  (not my work) Can i use fire bug to track down the scrip that is causing my element to disappear?

i.e configure firebug to watch my element > refresh > mouseOver > See what script file and what line the event is on?

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the element in the HTML (using inspection), right click on the node and select `Break On` > `Attribute Change`.

After that put the mouse over and you'll get the trace to the place that modifies the node

PS: I better like Chrome debugger for such kind of work - it has better (from my personal opinion) stack trace info.

Comment: Fantastic! So simple yet not obvious to me! Thanks for your help!